# Postgres: Optimize Query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a situation where I need to show a list of subjects to which a learning material or a test has been published to.
The query below works but it takes about ~8s. Is there a better way I can optimize this query?
Thank you.

```
SELECT sj.*, sj.id AS id FROM subjects sj 
WHERE ( 
    (SELECT COUNT(lmc.id) FROM learning_materials_codes lmc 
    INNER JOIN students s ON lmc.student_id = s.id 
    INNER JOIN learning_materials lm ON lmc.learning_material_id = lm.id 
    WHERE lmc.student_id = 1 AND sj.id = ANY(lm.subject_ids)) > 0 
        OR 
    (SELECT COUNT(tc.id) FROM test_codes tc 
    INNER JOIN students s ON tc.student_id = s.id 
    INNER JOIN tests t ON tc.test_id = t.id 
    WHERE tc.student_id = 1 AND t.subject_id = sj.id) > 0 
)
AND sj.school_id = 1
```

```
Table structure below

subjects
~~~~~~~~~~~
id
name
school_id
...

students
~~~~~~~~~~
id
f_name
l_name
school_id
...

tests
~~~~~~~~~
id
title
subject_id
...

test_codes
~~~~~~~~~~
test_id
student_id
code
...

learning_materials
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
id
title
subject_ids []
...

learning_material_codes
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
learning_material_id
student_id
code
...
```

Note:
Each time a learning material or a test is published an access code is generated for students and that data is kept in `learning_material_codes` or `test_codes` table

Comment: please provide table structure.

Comment: Why join to students?

Comment: Please show EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the query to

```
SELECT sj.*
FROM subjects sj 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM learning_materials_codes lmc 
                 INNER JOIN students s ON lmc.student_id = s.id
                 INNER JOIN learning_materials lm ON lmc.learning_material_id = lm.id
              WHERE lmc.student_id = 1
                AND sj.id = ANY(lm.subject_ids)
                AND lmc.id IS NOT NULL)
AND sj.school_id = 1
UNION
SELECT sj.*
FROM subjects sj 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM test_codes tc 
                 INNER JOIN students s ON tc.student_id = s.id 
                 INNER JOIN tests t ON tc.test_id = t.id 
              WHERE tc.student_id = 1
                AND t.subject_id = sj.id
                AND tc.id IS NOT NULL)
AND sj.school_id = 1;
```

That way, PostgreSQL can use a semi-join and may be faster. If you don't mind duplicate result rows, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` for better performance.

More performance may be gained with appropriate indexes, but it requires `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE, SETTINGS)` output to assess that.